# Linearization of the ODE system: Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control, nonlinear-dynamics

I have summarized the issues covered in the topics:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253133/linearization-of-ode-without-an-equilibrium

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253144/i-ask-for-help-with-commands-transferfunctionmodel-statespacemodel

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253092/plot3d-whenevent-ndsolve

---

*System of ODE:*

### $\begin{cases} \ddot{s}+\omega^2 \cdot s=0 \\ \dot{x}=G+u \\ \dot{z}+z=\frac{d}{dt}(-(x+s-1)^2) \\ \dot{G}+G=z \cdot s \\  \end{cases}$

**Problem:**

*All codes in Mathematica:*

*Given the ODE system:*

```
Clear["Derivative"]; ClearAll["Global`*"];

pars = {\[Alpha] = 1, \[Omega] = 2 Pi 2};

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{s''[t] + \[Omega]^2 s[t] == 0, x'[t] == G[t] + u[t], z'[t] + z[t] == D[-(x[t] + s[t] - 1)^2, t], G'[t] + G[t] == z[t] s[t]}, {{s[t], 0}, {s'[t], \[Alpha] \[Omega]}, {x[t], 0}, {z[t], 0}, {G[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {x[t], s[t], z[t], G[t]}, t];
```

---

*Calculating the required output signal:*

```
or = OutputResponse[asys, 0, {t, 0, 25}];

Plot[{or[[1]], 1}, {t, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> Full];
```

[image]

*If we do not take small oscillations (we do not need them) contained in the trajectory, then it is clear that this oscillatory transient process can be roughly described by a quasilinear law, which means that a certain transfer function corresponds to it.*

---

*Drawing on ideas from:*

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138852/linearization-of-a-nonlinear-system

*As well as:*

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246111/system-of-ode-rightarrow-affine-state-space-rightarrow-system-of-ode-in-ca

*I am trying to linearize the system at the equilibrium point using the Jacobi matrix. For some reason, one of the balance points is not searched for, so I set it manually:*

```
ClearAll[stateEqs]; stateEqs[Verbatim[AffineStateSpaceModel][{a_, b_, c_, d_}, x0_, u0_, y_, t_]] := Module[{u, x}, x = Replace[x0, {xx_, x1_} :> xx, 1]; u = Replace[u0, {uu_, u1_} :> uu, 1]; D[x, t] == a + b.u];
 
newode = asys // stateEqs // Thread; newode // ExpandAll // MapAt[Simplify, #, {All, 2}] & // Column // Expand;


eqns = ReplaceAll[newode /. Thread[Array[Subscript[\[FormalX], #] &, 5] -> {ds, s, x, z, G}] // DeleteCases[True], u[t] -> 0] // Expand;

eq = Solve[{s[t], -16 \[Pi]^2 ds[t], G[t], 2 G[t] - 2 ds[t] G[t] + 2 s[t] - 2 ds[t] s[t] - 2 G[t] x[t] - 2 s[t] x[t] - z[t], -G[t] + ds[t] z[t]} == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]}, Reals] // Simplify; (*Equilibrium Points*)

eq = {{ds[t] -> 0, s[t] -> 0, x[t] -> 0, z[t] -> 0, G[t] -> 0}}(*Handly equilibrium point*)
```

---

*Here I calculate the Jacobi matrix:*

```
j = D[{s[t], -16 \[Pi]^2 ds[t], G[t], 2 G[t] - 2 ds[t] G[t] + 2 s[t] - 2 ds[t] s[t] - 2 G[t] x[t] - 2 s[t] x[t] - z[t], -G[t] + ds[t] z[t]}, {{ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]}}];(*Jacobi Matrix*)

J = N[j /. eq[[1]]] // Simplify;

eqns = Thread[{ds'[t], s'[t], x'[t], z'[t], G'[t]} == J.{ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]} + {0, 0, u[t], 0, 0}];(*Collect ODE's*)

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[eqns, {{s[t], 0}, {s'[t], \[Alpha] \[Omega]}, {x[t], 0}, {z[t], 0}, {G[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {x[t]}, t](*Linearized Affine State-Space*)
```

---

*When calculating the output of a "linearized" system, I get sheer nonsense. Either I made a mistake in determining the stationary point, or something else.*

```
or2 = OutputResponse[asys, 0, {t, 0, 25}];

Plot[{or2}, {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200];
```

[image]

### Resume:

*Dear specialists.With all the obvious similarity of the transient processes in the original system, my attempts to describe it with a linear state-space repeatedly fail. Help me figure out this problem. Topic will be useful to others, and also give me a powerful impetus to understand the problem and master the tools. I would be grateful to everyone for help and advice .*

Comment: Could you add latex equations of some of the most important equations, since the mathematica code is harder to decipher. For the linearization that is giving you problems did you check if it might be unstable, i.e. look at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen 

$\begin{cases} \ddot{s}+\omega^2 \cdot s=0 \\ \dot{x}=G+u \\ \dot{z}+z=\frac{d}{dt}(-(x+s-1)^2) \\ \dot{G}+G=z \cdot s \\  \end{cases}$ 

and see my edit please. I include system of ODE on topic. Regarding the eigenvalues ... I have the impression that the linearized system is incorrect, i.e. during linearization, information about the position to which the system should come is lost). But these are just my thoughts.

P.S. $u=0$

Comment: Really, there is no need for the boldface text at the end. It makes the question look less interesting and even annoying for some readers. The context is well written and you don't need anything more

Comment: Could you add which equilibria you use and what the resulting corresponding Jacobian matrices are?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen 
eq = {{ds[t] -> 0, s[t] -> 0, x[t] -> 0, z[t] -> 0, G[t] -> 0}}(*Handly equilibrium point*) That's equilibrium point

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen j = D[{s[t], -16 \[Pi]^2 ds[t], G[t], 2 G[t] - 2 ds[t] G[t] + 2 s[t] - 2 ds[t] s[t] - 2 G[t] x[t] - 2 s[t] x[t] - z[t], -G[t] + ds[t] z[t]}, {{ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]}}];(*Jacobi Matrix and that Jacobi Matrix. It's a part of code from topic.

Comment: Isn't it that $x$ can be any constant at the equilibria? Furthermore, I believe the Jacobian is I believe always singular (at least one eigenvalue of zero) which means that one can't use the linearization to say something about whether an equilibrium is stable.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen No, $x$ cannot be any constant. In this system, $x$ reaches such a value that $-(x+s-1)^2=0$

Comment: But when all other states are zero and $x$ is some constant all time derivates are zero. It might be that the equilibria with nonzero $x$ are unstable such that the system in most cases does converge to $x=0$, but they are still equilibria.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen These are theoretical assumptions. Try to simulate the system and you will see that it always converges to a certain state.

Comment: (1) Why is everything italics? It is so hard to read.
(2) what is the question precisely?
(3) Why do you consider that output nonsense? I don't...I see it as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will first write your system of differential equations as a system of first order differential equations and group some terms. It is,
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{s} &= q,\\
\dot{q} &= -\omega^2\, s,\\
\dot{x} &= G + u,\\
\dot{z} &= -z - 2(x + s - 1)(G - q) - 2(x + s - 1)\,u,\\
\dot{G} &= -G + z\, s
\end{aligned}$$
Mathematica does produce the right model from your equations and, if you run `asys` through `StateSpaceModel`, it produces the right linearization too:

[image: Linearization of dynamics about the desired equilibrium point.]

You do not need to compute it manually as you try to. However, as Kwin points out, the correct linearization has eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. This means that the behaviour of the linearized system does *not* mimic the local behaviour of the original nonlinear system. The eigenvalues, by the way, are $\pm 4 \pi\,i,$ $-1,$ $-1,$ and $0.$ As a result, there is no use in acquiring the output response of the linearized system since it will tell you nothing useful; any conclusion you draw from it would be unfounded.

Even if that was not the case, your output response is expected. You computed the output response of a linear state-space model with zero input. The output is zero in that case. The output response computes the output $y(t)$ given an input $u(t)$ assuming the initial condition is at the equilibrium point. Compute the step response (pass $1$ instead of $0$) and you'll see something. If you instead compute the state response (using `StateResponse`) with a non-zero initial condition for the linear system, then you will observe non-trivial behaviour.

All of that said, you can still perform linear control design and stabilize the system locally if you really want to. But that should address your question about the output of the linearized system.